# Deploy an ASP.NET WebSite on an Azure Cloud Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

Can i deploy an ASP.NET WebSite (not ASP.NET WebApplication) on an Microsoft Azure Cloud Service WebRole?

Or must I deploy it on Azure WebSite?

Comment: normally I do it on Azure Websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason you can't.  [This article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm) outlines some of the criteria you can use to decide whether to use Websites or Cloud Services.